# Asp.net MVC 5 Identity Access

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am creating a project using ASP.NET MVC 5.

I used Identity to get user information.

Using migrations I created fields like FirstName, LastName

But how do I use that? I have this:

```
 @using MTC.Models


 @helper Render(MTC.Post post, System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, bool showComments)
   {
     {
        var user = new ApplicationUser();
        user.FirstName.ToString();
     }
   }
```

And it returns this:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

All I want to do is get it to display the name from the database.

I am  trying to learn the backend. Sorry If this is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you are creating new object of `ApplicationUser` without initializing its values. So every property of this object will be null. You need to either first assign value to it or fetch user from database.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating UserID column in your table along with Names of user and get User Name from the table by:

```
string Name = User.Identity.GetUserId();        
return View(Database.Table.Where(r =>r.UserID == Name).ToList());
```

You can do this in your controller and also in your view.